# Comparing $n \log_2 (n) /2$ and $\log_2 n!$ asymptotically

Tags: limits, analysis, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, asymptotics

I want to compare $n \log_2 (n) /2$ and $\log_2 n!$.

I calculated $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\frac{n\log_2(n)}{2}}{\log_2 n!} = \infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log_2 n!}{\frac{n\log_2(n)}{2}} = 2$. What does this mean now? Intuitively I would say that the numerator is faster if the limit is infinity. But for  the second case with $2$ I would also say that the numerator is faster. Not both can be true obviously.

Comment: Did you use the Sterling approximation to estimate the $n!$ term?

Comment: Since either of them should be false, I reccomend you to provide your calculation steps so that others can check them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider $f(x)=\ln(x)$ over the interval $[1,n]$.
 $\log(x)$ is a concave function, hence by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality)

$$ \int_{1}^{n}\ln(x)\,dx \geq \ln(2)+\ln(3)+\ldots+\ln(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(n) \tag{1}$$
which is equivalent to
$$ \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln(n)- n+1 \geq \ln(n!).\tag{2} $$
It is not difficult to show that the difference between the LHS and the RHS of $(1)$ is bounded, hence
$$\boxed{ \ln(n!) = \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln(n)-n + O(1)}\tag{3} $$
Proof of boundedness: let us consider the graph of $\ln(x)$ and the graph of the line through $(k;\ln(k))$ and $(k+1;\ln(k+1))$ over the interval $[k,k+1]$, for some $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$. The maximum difference between these functions is achieved at the point for which the derivative of $\ln(x)$ equals the slope of the line, i.e. at the solution of
$$ \frac{1}{x}=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right). $$
At this point the difference equals
$$\begin{eqnarray*} && -\ln\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)-\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}-k\right)+\ln(k)\right)\\&=&k\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)-\ln\left(k \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)-1=\frac{1}{8k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right). \end{eqnarray*}$$